# How to know the last attendance action of the current user ('sign_in' or 'sign_out') in odoo 9?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I have extended the hr_attendance module and I want to get the last value of 'action' of the current logged user (It can be 'sign_in' or 'sign_out')

I don't know how to access to that value.

In the attendance module there are these functions:

```
def _altern_si_so(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
...

def _state(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None)
...
```

But I don't know how to call that functions inside the extended module or if there is another way to get that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking the database tables I found the solution:

## First we obtain the employee_id associated to the logged user

```
employee_id = {}
cr.execute('SELECT hr.id \
            FROM resource_resource AS res JOIN hr_employee AS hr \
            ON res.id = hr.resource_id \
            WHERE res.user_id = %s',[uid])
for res in cr.fetchall():
    employee_id = res[0]
```

## Then, we get the last action of the employee_id

```
last_action = {}
cr.execute('SELECT hr_attendance.action \
            FROM hr_attendance \
            WHERE employee_id = %s',[employee_id])
for res in cr.fetchall():
    last_action = res[0]
```

'last_action' has now "sign_in" or "sign_out" (The last action done by the current user in the attendance module)